# Unable to loop through Nested Loop (Python)

Tags: python, numpy, loops, nested

I am attempting to do a nested loop in order to find the mean-squared for a variety of different sized distributions. I keep getting an error that reads: "ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (0,) into shape (1000,)".

I am a beginner coder so I know this may be trivial for some...

My code:

```
#%% Initialize variables. 
rng = np.random.default_rng()
rand = rng.random
num_steps = 1000
num_walks = 1000
x_step = np.zeros((num_steps, num_walks))
y_step = np.zeros((num_steps, num_walks))
x_final = np.zeros((1, num_walks))  
y_final = np.zeros((1, num_walks))
displacement = np.zeros((num_walks, 1))
mean_squared_displacement = np.zeros(10)


#%% Find the mean-squared displacement for a variety of step numbers. 

step_variation = np.linspace(0, 10000, 11)
for n in range(np.size(step_variation)-1):
    for m in range(num_walks):
        
        x_step[:,m] = np.cumsum(2*(rand(int(step_variation[n]))<.5)-1)  # ERROR APPEARS ON THIS LINE                          
                                                                                

        y_step[:,m] = np.cumsum(2*(rand(int(step_variation[n]))<.5)-1)                            
                                                                                 
        x_final[0,m] = x_step[-1,m]
         
        y_final[0,m] = y_step[-1,m]
        
        displacement[m,0] = np.sqrt(x_final[0,m]**2 + y_final[0,m]**2)  
    
    mean_squared_displacement[n] = np.mean(displacement[m,0]**2)
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post the [*full text* of any errors or tracebacks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146).

Answer (score 0):

What steps did you take to debug this?  Any? or did you just throw your hands up in despair, not understanding that the error means?

Did you examine the problem line?  Test pieces in it?

```
x_step[:,m] = np.cumsum(2*(rand(int(step_variation[n]))<.5)-1)
```

The first value of `step_variation` is 0 (from `linspace`).  `rand(0)` produces a (0,) shape array.  The rest of that expression is thus also (0,) shape.

```
In [13]: rand(0)
Out[13]: array([], dtype=float64)
```

`x_step` is (1000,1000), so `x_step[:,m]` is (1000,) shape.  The error tells us/you that it can't put a (0,) (no values) array into that (1000,) shape slot.

Comment: I understand what the error is saying, but I'm trying to figure out how to get the code to do what I want. I noticed that when I put in any integer value in place of the step_variation[n] value it worked fine. But then that doesn't do a calculation for the various values of steps. I believe the error lies within the structure of the loop, not the error that is displayed. But I can't figure out what that is.

Comment: Does `step_variation` have to start with 0?  The assignment will work only if the `cumsum` produces 1 or 1000 values.  I don't know what you are trying to do here, so can't suggest a correction.

Comment: Actually I've figured it out. I added a couple lines to replace the array x_step and y_step to match the dimensions for every iteration. You helped point me in the right direction. Thank you!